# NSPasteBoard get file from the Download (Grid View) in dock via DragAndDrop to App Statusbar Icon

Tags: macos, cocoa, nspasteboard

I Implemented drag and drop functionality in a cocoa app that I am working on.
When I drag and drop files, from a folder or from the desktop or from any specific location on the hard drive, onto the status bar icon of my app, the app appropriately detects it and I am able to work with the file without any issues at all.

The problem that I encounter is that if I click the Downloads icon in the dock (it opens in grid view) and from there I select a file and drag and drop it to the status bar, then the app does not detect it at all. The "performDragOperation" is not even called in this scenario. I think this is because the Downloads Grid is not a specific location, instead it is a representation of the Downloads folder presented on the desktop.

This is where I register for the Drag types:

```
- (id)initWithStatusItem:(NSStatusItem *)statusItem {
CGFloat itemWidth = [statusItem length];
CGFloat itemHeight = [[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] thickness];
NSRect itemRect = NSMakeRect(0.0, 0.0, itemWidth, itemHeight);
self = [super initWithFrame:itemRect];

if (self != nil) {
    _statusItem = statusItem;
    _statusItem.view = self;
}

NSArray *dragTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSFilenamesPboardType, NSURLPboardType, nil];
[self registerForDraggedTypes:dragTypes];

return self;
```

}

Here is the draggingEntered method:

```
- (NSDragOperation)draggingEntered:(id<NSDraggingInfo>)sender {
ApplicationDelegate *appdelegate = (ApplicationDelegate *)[[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

if (!appdelegate.isApplicationLoggedIn) {
    return NSDragOperationNone;
}

if ([sender draggingSourceOperationMask] & NSDragOperationCopy) {
    return NSDragOperationCopy;
}

if ([[sender draggingPasteboard] availableTypeFromArray:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSFilenamesPboardType, NSURLPboardType, nil]]) {
    return NSDragOperationCopy;
}

return NSDragOperationNone;
```

}

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thank You.